# What is the acces order of a Index B-Tree in Oracle?

Tags: sql, orm

This is the B-Tree index who contains by example the id of the members of my table member.

[image]

If I have this request:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM member;
```

The order of acces is

> 23 -> 11 -> 1 -> 13 -> 23 -> 33 -> 25 -> 77

OR

> 23 -> 23 -> 11 -> 23 -> 11 -> 1 -> 23 -> 11 -> 13 -> 23 -> 33 -> 23
> -> 33 -> 25 -> 23 -> 33 -> 77

Is it necessary to always return to the root to analyze all nodes of the B-Tree index ?

Comment: Are you certain that Oracle is storing the data as you've illustrated?

Comment: What is the “root” and why is B-Tree “analysis” _in SQL_, presuming such is an actual and simplistic implementation, useful?

Comment: I don't know but in my lesson SQL which use as reference Oracle there is the index B-Tree. One of the exercice is to create a B-Tree index with this number of id members: 1,11,13,23,25,33,77 and after that I have to explain the way used for several requests and one of them is  "SELECT count(*) FROM member;".

Comment: root is the origine, the number 23 in my picture.

Comment: The Oracle implementation is less relevant for your studies, as it could be performed as an in-order, pre-order, or post-order traversal. Also relevant is understanding depth first versus breadth first traversals. If anything, that's what is important for your lesson - not how Oracle may do it.

Comment: Ok may be not only for Oracle I change the tag

Comment: "Is it necessary to always return to the root to analyze all nodes of the B-Tree index ?" - Absolutely not, especially as you've illustrated in your second example. General methods for identifying elements in a B-Tree are depth first and breadth first searches. General traversals are in-order, pre-order, or post-order. Research those 5 items and you'll understand how it works in practice.

Comment: I know the general methods, but which of them is used in a B-Tree "by default". My exercice doesn't specify which method is used. There are just " Represent the index", "For the following queries explain the way used in the index".

Comment: There is no "default" method. They each have strengths and weaknesses. If your assignment is asking a specific question without providing a traversal method, then important details are missing.

Comment: Yes, missing some precisions for be do it. Thank you  h0r53 for your responses!